# How to write deferrable SqlSensor in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I have a number of DAGs that wait for EOD settlement, and limited worker slot. The settlement ends at varying times. So while waiting the settlement, I want to run a different DAG on the worker slot. From Airflow documentation, deferable operator looks fit for this kind of purpose. I'm new to python and airflow. Can somebody explain how to write deferable sql sensor ?

I have looked at deferable time sensor examples, but can't make it to work with sql sensors.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need and came across your post when searching for solutions.

I do not know python (especially asynchronous python) or airflow, but was able to rig up something that works using examples at https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/airflow/triggers and https://github.com/astronomer/astronomer-providers/tree/main/astronomer/providers.

My intent in posting this is to get feedback / suggestion for improvements -- especially with respect to awaiting blocking code.

**SqlTrigger**

```
import asyncio

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from airflow.triggers.base import BaseTrigger, TriggerEvent
from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook

class SqlTrigger(BaseTrigger):
    """
    A trigger that fires after running a sql statement until records are returned
    :param conn_id: connection id
    :param sql: The sql to run
    :param poke_interval:
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        conn_id: str, 
        sql: str, 
        poke_interval: float = 60,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.conn_id = conn_id
        self.sql = sql
        self.poke_interval = poke_interval
        self.hook = BaseHook.get_hook(self.conn_id)     # should this be in run()?

    def serialize(self):
        return (
            "eta.triggers.sql.SqlTrigger", 
            {
                "conn_id": self.conn_id,
                "sql": self.sql,
                "poke_interval": self.poke_interval,
            },
        )

    async def run(self):
        # hook = self._get_hook()
        while True:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as exe:
                future = exe.submit(self._get_records)
                records = future.result()
                if records:
                    yield TriggerEvent(True)
            await asyncio.sleep(self.poke_interval)

    def _get_records(self):
        return self.hook.get_records(self.sql)

    def _get_hook(self) -> BaseHook:
        return BaseHook.get_hook(self.conn_id)
```

**DeferrableSqlSensor**

```
from typing import Iterable

from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator

from eta.triggers.sql import SqlTrigger

class DeferrableSqlSensor(BaseSensorOperator):

    template_fields: Iterable[str] = ('sql', )

    template_ext = ('.sql', '.hql',)

    def __init__(
        self, *,
        conn_id: str,
        sql: str,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.conn_id = conn_id
        self.sql = sql

    def execute(self, context):
        self.defer(
            trigger=SqlTrigger(conn_id=self.conn_id, sql=self.sql, poke_interval=self.poke_interval), 
            method_name="execute_complete"
        )

    def execute_complete(self, context, event=None):
        # We have no more work to do here. Mark as complete.
        return
```

And the task in my dag looks like below:

```
test_deferrable_sql_sensor = DeferrableSqlSensor(
    task_id = 'test_deferrable_sql_sensor',
    conn_id = 'mysql_default',
    sql = "select * from Tasks where task_id = '123' and status = 'completed'",
    poke_interval = 20,
)
```

Comment: I see this occasionally: "ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.20 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger" even when I have "INFO - 0 triggers currently running". Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Probably a red herring. You should [contribute this to the OSS community](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/CONTRIBUTORS_QUICK_START.rst) :)