# How to debug blocking in a python async function

Tags: python, airflow, python-asyncio

I have zero knowledge of asynchronous python other than several hours of searching stackoverflow posts, and am struggling to figure out what is, occasionally, causing the below error:

> Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 0.26 seconds, likely by a
> badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more
> information on overrunning coroutines

Setting PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 is not giving me anything I am capable of understanding:

> WARNING - Executing <Task pending name='Task-3'
> coro=<TriggerRunner.run_trigger() running at
> /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/triggerer_job.py:358>
> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at
> 0x7f2ded110e50>()] created at
> /usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:422> created at
> /usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:382> took 0.441 seconds

I think the blocking is happening in below code snippet.

```
async def run(self):
    while True:
        # ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-threadpoolexecutor-in-python3/
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exe:
            future = exe.submit(self._get_records)
            records = future.result()
            if records:
                yield TriggerEvent(True)
        await asyncio.sleep(self.poke_interval)

def _get_records(self):
    return self.hook.get_records(self.sql)
```

For further reference, complete code as well as the intent of what I am trying to accomplish is here: [How to write deferrable SqlSensor in Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440435/how-to-write-deferrable-sqlsensor-in-airflow)

Thanks in advance for any advice on debugging / fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, as you written it will offload the blocking part to be executed in another thread - which is ok, and then *immediately block the main thread* until the work is complete in that other thread, by calling `future.result()`: you are using `concurrent.futures` with no provision to take any advantage of the asyncio in the main thread. The hint to find out this call is blocking is that there is no `await` in front of it.

You can do this instead:

```
async def run(self):
    exe = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with exe:
      while True:
        records = await loop.run_in_executor(exe, self._get_records)
            
        if records:
            yield TriggerEvent(True)
        await asyncio.sleep(self.poke_interval)
```

(Also in your code you were creating and shutting down the executor - with its threads - in each interation of the outer `while` loop)

This, as is will offload each call to a different thread, but still won 't do any calls in parallel - if you want up to 5 calls in parallel, please make that explicit, along with the limit requirement you are trying to implement with the `asyncio.sleep` call - possibily in another question.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! I still come across the error, but with dramatically lower frequency -- perhaps there's another issue. Nonetheless, I accept this as the answer as it has really enhanced my understanding and solved the issue for all practical purposes.

Comment: Also, please delete the line "ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-threadpoolexecutor-in-python3/" -- not relevant any more and could mislead someone.