# Use result of SqlSensor query as input to subsequent tasks

Tags: python, sql, mysql, airflow

I am new to airflow and am trying to solve the following problem.

We have a mysql database, and we want to export records to a files as they become an available.

I have the SQL query I need to execute.  In our current (non airflow) implementation, we do work on the records returned if there are any, and do nothing if now rows are returned.

This seems like a good fit for the [SqlSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/_api/airflow/sensors/sql/index.html). In particular, `fail_on_empty` seems like a good fit for this, since the rest of the dag should not be executed if there are no rows.

However, if there are rows, I would like to pass them to subsequent tasks in the dag. I can't figure out if this is supported with built in operators.  I can implement this with a custom operator (possible using the TaskFlow api and Sql hook), but I'd like to use the out of the box operators and sensors if possible. I'd also like to be able to only query the database once, and not have a first query to check and a second query to retrieve the values.

Can what I'm describing be easily accomplished with airflow built-ins?

**EDIT: I just discovered [custom xcomm backends](https://blog.devgenius.io/implementing-a-custom-xcom-backend-on-airflow-using-azure-blob-storage-2ddd1151e6d0)**

Now I am thinking: I can execute the the query in one go and persist it's result, and return it from the first task. Then, the subsequent task can process that, and if there is no data (and thus an empty file), it can skip the rest of the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Airflow sensors are typically used to [wait for something to happen](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/sensors.html).

So, in your case, the `SqlSensor` will be used to detect the presence of data in a table; if data exists, then process it in a subsequent task. You could pass something like `select count(*)` as the `sql` parameter. If the result of `select count(*)` is greater than 0, then it will be determined to have been successful and the downstream task could to something more complex by using the [SQLExecuteQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-common-sql/stable/_api/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql/index.html#airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql.SQLExecuteQueryOperator).

How to do this correctly depends on your specific use case, but the best way would probably be to create a SqlTrigger similar to what you see [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657594/7004653) so that the sensor can execute asynchronously. You could have a DAG that runs on a `@continuous` schedule just uses this `SqlSensor` to use [data aware scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html) to trigger a downstream DAG that actually does the processing.

Comment: Just a small addition to your answer: make sure not to use `fail_on_empty` and `select count(*)` together as while it technically would work, but logically it makes no sense as the `count` always returns 1 row

Comment: What I want is for a way to do this all with a single query. Maybe I'd have to right a custom operator with a hook to achieve this. That way i could have the data and do the conditional check in the operator.

Comment: You could write a deferrable operator that polls using `select count(*)`, then once the condition is satisfied actually executes the `insert into ... select * from` query